# filter dataframe by value counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

been trying this for a while but not getting anywhere.
Please consider the DF below.

```
    Id  YearBuilt  SalePrice Neighborhood
    1       2003     208500      CollgCr
    2       1976     181500      Veenker
    3       2001     223500      CollgCr
    4       1915     140000      Crawfor
    5       2000     250000      NoRidge
    6       1993     143000      Mitchel
    7       2004     307000      Somerst
    8       1973     200000       NWAmes
    9       1931     129900      OldTown
    10       1939     118000      BrkSide
    11       1965     129500       Sawyer
    12       2005     345000      NridgHt
    13       1962     144000       Sawyer
    14       2006     279500      CollgCr
    15       1960     157000        NAmes
    16       1929     132000      BrkSide
    17       1970     149000        NAmes
```

I want to group the data into neighborhoods and if the count of neighborhood is less than say 10, it should be put into a group `other`. I have seen other answers but been unable to interpret them. I have tried

```
house_df['newColumn'] = house_df['Neighborhood'].mask(house_df['Neighborhood'].count < 50, 'other')
```

also tried

```
house_df.groupby['Neighborhood'].filter(lambda x: x.count < 10)
```

but this doesnt work. also tried to `groupby` neighborhood and apply a filter but no go. please help.

This is an example of what I am looking to achieve

```
 Id  YearBuilt  SalePrice Neighborhood newColumn
1       2003     208500      CollgCr   Collgcr
2       1976     181500      Veenker    other
3       2001     223500      CollgCr    CollgCr
4       1915     140000      Crawfor    other
5       2000     250000      NoRidge    NoRidge
6       1993     143000      Mitchel    Mitchel
7       2004     307000      Somerst    other
8       1973     200000       NWAmes    NWAmes
```

Comment: Show the other failed attempt please.

Comment: `house_df.groupby['Neighborhood'].filter(lambda x: x.count < 10)`

Comment: Please edit your question. That is relevant information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `value_counts` to count the neighborhoods and `map` with a `lambda` to produce an appropriate grouping.

```
vc = df.Neighborhood.value_counts()

df = df.assign(
    newColumn=df.Neighborhood.map(
        lambda x: x if vc.at[x] > 1 else 'other'
    )
)
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want to put the `Neighborhood` into the group `other` if the count of neighborhood is less than 10. In other words I want to reduce the dimension and put the neighborhoods occuring less than 10 in `other` group

Comment: @Harj that's what I've done. Except I used less than 2 because you didn't give enough data to show what it'd look like with 10. If this still isn't what you want, consider editing your question and make it clear what you do want.

Comment: I dont get an error but `newColumn` does not get created